# Encryption - Strings Corrupting

Tags: php, url, encryption

I've noticed recently that some of the links in our application are corrupting...

By corrupting, I mean, when the string is encrypted and then decrypted the output is not the same as the input, the output becomes a complete mess of gibberish.

```
function encode($string) { 
    $key = 'Gt88ggjJI_987JKbgKHIfgIKhOknoUa6'; 
    return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key)))); 
}

function decode($string) { 
    $key = 'Gt88ggjJI_987JKbgKHIfgIKhOknoUa6'; 
    return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($string), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0"); 
}
```

*Please excuse the function names, I know the difference between (en|de)coding and (en|de)crypting. Unfortunately it needs to be called that for legacy reasons.*

Sometimes $string is sent over a URI GET (and no it doesn't contain terribly sensitive information, let's keep on topic please), when it is sent via GET:

```
href="/path/to/thingy/?x=<?= urlencode(encode('my amazing string')); ?>"
```

and the PHP on the receiving end, automatically urldecode's and then:

```
$string = decode($_GET['x']);
```

But sadly, about 1 in 400 encrypts/decrypts the output is wrong. Can anyone lend a hand or explain where I'm going wrong?

Sometimes when the string is sent via a cookie, it also corrupts. Is this something to do with the functions, urlencode or maybe client browsers not sending the data correctly due to shaky internet connections?

Comment: `base64_decode($string)` ... Might want to trim it before decoding it. Also, would it be possible to see values that work, and values that do not work?

Comment: are you adding any padding for the encryption? Since you're using CBC there should be some padding options unless you can guarantee key string and binary length should always be the same.

Comment: Are you sending multibyte characters across?

Comment: @SébastienRenauld - If it's needed I might be able to provide examples of corruption, but if they can be decoded - they would contain peoples fullnames and I wouldn’t be comfortable showing them.

Comment: @Dave - I'm a noob when it comes to this subject. I'm only sending plain text strings [a-Z0-9 \-], sadly I haven’t looked into what CBC or padding does and I don't know what multibyte characters are :(

Comment: @Dave, nice pick, but he's using 32-char - 256bit - MD5 output on both. phpisuber01, base64 guarantees that it wouldn't. I'm pretty sure it's a trimming issue (i.e. a space) or badly-encoded URI where a = would go past and be evaluated, but need some examples to track it down.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld yeah was a shot in the dark I rarely use CBC but I remember last time I fiddled I was having a nightmare with double == at the end of the encrypted string which was breaking the decrypt. Turned out it was because i was using pkcs_8 padding (as c# said it used) when in fact using mcrypt and php I needed to use pkcs_7 pad or 5 if the input string was of an exact length

Comment: @SébastienRenauld - I'm sure this string was only a company name originally and will be safe to display, this was the output after the decode (this one was sent via a GET)

    "æþð.õý`¯õfã*o‰©æv¿yÏÒÛµ"

Comment: By "values", I meant the base64_encoded values that you pass through URL.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Ok, I ran this example codepastebin.com/iFGXjLJe and these are the outputs, I hope these are the values you need. "MEjmXfHEk1hd%2F5XyYZiLnFJt3FfOP3OYQqsJQns0DOM%3D" and "k40YQxAOVosoRYtjkRoNkEnk1ZWImYe9HAEIw7O2IPc

Comment: What I meant was values that would trigger a failed decryption.

Comment: Looks like there's some HTML chars making their way into your encrypted string prehaps from your urlencode.  I've highlighted them below with !! either side of it.  Make sure you're urldecoding() before you process the string to return those html chars back to usable chars other wise you'll attempt to decrypt %2F etc `MEjmXfHEk1hd!!%2F!!5XyYZiLnFJt3FfOP3OYQqsJQns0DOM!!%3D!!`

Comment: OK, doesn't PHP do that automatically?